# Replacing part of regex

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I trying to replace '.' between two not number symbols. I used replaceAll and regEx

```
string.replaceAll("\\D\\.\\D", "_");
```

but it changing and symbols near '.' Can I solve this with Java methods or I should write own method?

Comment: You'll probably want to read up on RegEx (non) capture groups and lookahead/lookbehind.

Comment: What are you trying to replace, and with what? Currently, out of a pattern `AB.CD`, this would return `A.D`, having matching 1 char either side of the `.`

Comment: replace `"."` with `"."` ?. I am assuming in my answer that you want to replace `"."` with `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may work for you:

```
yourString.replaceAll("(\\D)[.](\\D)","$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex like this :
`(?<=\D)(\.)(?=\D)`

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/uM2dE1/1)

Your issue is : the \D parts will also be selected.

example :

```
System.out.println("1.1".replaceAll("(?<=\\D)(\\.)(?=\\D)", "")); // output : 1.1
System.out.println("a.b".replaceAll("(?<=\\D)(\\.)(?=\\D)", "")); // output : ab
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, out of a pattern `AB.CD`, this would return `A.D`, having matched and replaced only 1 char either side of the `.` (the `B` and the `C`)

This is what I think you're trying for:

```
string.replaceAll("[^0-9]+\\.[^0-9]+", ".");
```

But I'm unclear from your description what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: No. he doesn't want the numbers to be replaced. He wants only the dot to be replaced

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure that `replaceAll` is the right tool. Does it work with captured groups?